# Keep getting syntax error when "rake db:migrate"

Tags: ruby, activerecord, migration, syntax-error, rake

My code:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :artist
   has_many :song_genres
   has_many :genres, :through :song_genres
end
```

Error:

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: .../app/models/song.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
has_many :genres, :through :song_genres
```

When I use "=>":

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :song_genres
  has_many :genres, :through => :song_genres
end
```

I don't get an error message anymore but now I get another error message for a similar situation in one of my migrations.

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: .../db/migrate/01_create_artists_table.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_end
                t.string :name
```

And the code there looks like this:

```
class CreateArtistsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
        create_table :artists |t|
        t.string :name
        t.has_many :songs 
        t.has_many :genres, through: :song_genres 
        end 
  end
end
```

Im a newbie so I would really appreciate the help! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two problems here. In your model, you're getting the syntax for keyword arguments wrong. In ruby, you can pass arguments as keywords by putting the colon **after** the keyword and before the value, like so `key: :value` rather then `:key :value`. The colon before a word declares a symbol, which isn't what you're doing here. So, your model should actually be this:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :artist
   has_many :song_genres
   # has_many :genres, :through :song_genres
   has_many :genres, through: :song_genres
   # Which is shorthand for `has_many :genres, :through => :song_genres`
end
```

And, in your migration, you can't specify `through`. That's something that only exists in your models. You've also got the syntax for a migration wrong. It should look more like this:

```
create_table :table_name do |t|
  t.type :column_name
end
```

When you say `t.has_many`, you're asking ActiveRecord to create a column with type "has_many" which isn't a valid type. Instead, you want something like `string`, `integer`, `datetime`, etc. For a reference to another table, you can do `t.references`. So, your migration should look more like this:

```
class CreateArtistsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
        create_table :artists |t|
        t.string :name
        t.<type> :songs 
        t.<type> :genres #, through: :song_genres 
        end 
  end
end
```

Specifically, given the relationships you're trying to create, it'll be more like this:

```
class CreateArtistsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :artists |t|
      t.string :name
    end 
    add_reference :songs, :artist
    create_table :song_genres do |t|
      t.references :song
      t.references :genre
    end
  end
end
```

As a side note, in ruby you should be using 2 spaces for indentation.

Comment: Is this `t.<type> :genres, through: :song_genres ` possible in migration? I never saw or used it.

Comment: No, it's not, I was just trying to correct `t.has_many` before correcting the rest of the errors.

Comment: `CreateArtistsTable` migration should not create 2 different tables. It works, but semantic is wrong.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with creating 2 tables in one migration. In fact, for a many-to-many relationship, that's often the best way to do it.

Comment: No it is not. Your answer is misleading. They works, but that is not how you advise others to do it. Create a separate migrations for them.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I may be wrong, and I'd be happy to edit my answer if I am. Can you point me to any authoritative sources which say that creating multiple tables in one migration is bad practice?

Answer (score -1):

`create_table :artists |t|` should be `create_table :artists do |t|`

Also, the below 2 lines should not be inside `artists` migrations. They are wrong. This is not how has many through relationships are created in Rails. They should be part of the model, not the migrations.

```
t.has_many :songs 
t.has_many :genres, through: :song_genres
```

Inside `Song` model, write it like.

```
has_many :genres, through: :song_genres
```

Create a migration for `song_genres` table like to set up the has many though relationships.

```
create_table :song_genres do |t|
  t.belongs_to :songs
  t.belongs_to :genres
end
```

Comment: I've downvoted your answer because I think it's unfair to other answerers to try to get in first by posting a short answer and editing it over and over again. I saw your first iteration, and it was very incomplete, and am down voting based on that.

Comment: @thesecretmaster I answer it this way. Welcome your downvote! We are not in a race.

Answer (score -1):

Try following syntax for your first error message:

`has_many :genres, through: :song_genres`